# How to manually turn off Rift S Touch controllers when not in use?

Tags: oculus-rift

I have been using the Rift S headset for a couple of weeks now, and one thing I have noticed, is that the controllers stay on anytime the headset is in use.

This makes sense when you are using the controllers, but when playing a game like Elite Dangerous - where I am using a Xbox One controller or HOTAS - there is no reason for them to be on.

The batteries are being drained for no reason because of this. Is there any way to turn them off other than removing the batteries?